# The Monitor's screen can't fill up on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: display-resolution

I am using ubuntu 20.04 for a few months and feel good. Recently I bought a new E-ink monitor, the model is 'Paperlike HD' from Dasung, which has a resolution of 2200*1650 (4:3). But when I connected it to my computer, Ubuntu 20.04 did not have the right resolution for it.

If I use the default 2200×1650, the monitor can display normally, but for a 13.3-inch screen, the resolution is too high, all font and icons are very small, and the image seems a bit unstable. If I switch to other 4:3 resolutions, such as 1600×1200 or 1280×1024, the display will ok, but only the middle part of the screen can display content, and the image will not automatically stretch and fill up the entire screen.

I did not encounter this problem under Windows 7, because I can set the option of filling the screen up in the AMD catalyst utility, but I don’t know if there is a similar method under Ubuntu 20.04, and the monitor itself does not have a menu to set zoom the image, Can someone provide some advice to me? Thanks a lot.

This is output message from xrander:

```
sunjar@Ubuntu360:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2880 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-D-1 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024     60.02 +  75.02* 
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      75.05    60.04    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   960x720       75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    75.00    72.81    75.00    66.67    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       70.08  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 connected 1600x1200+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 200mm x 150mm
   2200x1650     40.00 +
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00* 
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I was trid use this,but it didn't work.

```
sunjar@Ubuntu360:~$xrandr --output HDMI1 --fbmm 280x215
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the scale factor from System Settings?...

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have changed the scale factor settting, but it's dosn't work, the content in display area has become big, but display area still not filled up.

Comment: @SunJar did u resolve this issue? if so how?

Comment: @Ekaveera Gouribhatl，No, I give up, I replaced a new display adatpter now it works.